# Reason to add empty source file to a STATIC library?

Tags: c++, cmake

I've seen this quite a lot in C++, that developers add an empty source file to the library in CMake. One example is [here](https://github.com/ethz-asl/okvis/blob/f0c9ba472b89f85030cd58dfbae03ceec7817679/okvis_kinematics/CMakeLists.txt#L10), with the empty source file found [here](https://github.com/ethz-asl/okvis/blob/master/okvis_kinematics/src/dependency-tracker.cc).
The CMake file has this line:

```
# build the library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC src/dependency-tracker.cc)
```

This is only the case if there are no other source files in the `src` folder, so the library would be 'header only'. Why do they do this?

---

The directory structure i was referring to:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── okvis
│       └── kinematics
│           ├── implementation
│           │   └── Transformation.hpp   <- header only implementation
│           ├── operators.hpp
│           └── Transformation.hpp
├── src
│   └── dependency-tracker.cc   <- empty source file
└── test
    ├── runTests.cpp
    └── TestTransformation.cpp
```

Comment: isn't the name `dependency-tracker` self explanatory?

Comment: what does it mean? it track the dependency, but what dependency, what happens if I don't have it?

Comment: "Why do they do this?" - I fear that only **developers** of the project may answer that question for sure. Others could only **guess** their reasoning. It could be that the developer think "every functionality needs a library". If could be that the developer isn't aware of `INTERFACE` library, which could represent a header-only library and which can be used for linking and installing. It could be that CMake 2.8.11 doesn't handle `INTERFACE` library well. It could be many other possible reasons.

Comment: My first guess was also what @Tsyvarev said, and his comment could easily (and most probably) be an answer to this question. If set correctly, `INTERFACE` will also track dependencies, compile options, etc.

Comment: thanks @Tsyvarev, I think I understood your explanation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The project specifies CMake 2.8.11 as a minimal requirement:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
```

This version [lacks](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:add_library) for `INTERFACE` library type, which nowadays is a standard representation of a *header-only* library. (Support for INTERFACE libraries firstly [appeared](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html) in CMake 3.0).

Without `INTERFACE` library available, a normal library with a single empty source file looks like a good alternative.

I don't know why `dependency-tracker.cc` name choosen for the empty source file. Probably, this name has some special meaning for the project's developers.